JPA: Reference to a single cell instead fo the whole row
I have 2 entities that persist into a DB.
@Entity
// bid is a foreign key to B (id)
public class A
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column (unique = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String name;

    @Column (unique = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long bid;  // foreign key to B (id)

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "bid", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Getter
    private B b;
}



@Entity
public class B
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column (unique = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String info;
}

This is working well.
public interface ARepo extends JpaRepository <A, Long>
{   
    public List <A> findByName (String name);
}

findByName delivers A-objects where member getB returns object of B.
But I do not want the whole B, I only want B.info.
Can I change the @JoinColumn to get only that single element instead of the whole row?

You can not. It is against relational database conventions. JPA is a model of relational database.

@Alex In SQL you can select only one field from a whole table while at the same time filtering to get this field from only one row. The relational concepts are not the limitation here.

@queeg The question was about @JoinColumn . It defines a foreign key, that points to another table. The whole table. We can not fulfill requirement by changing @JoinColumn only. We may do as you said, or define a view with all columns from A and needed columns from B. But this is outside the question and not asked.

It should be possible using JPA
@Query(
value = "SELECT a.info FROM A a WHERE a.name = :name", nativeQuery = true)

But you problem then end up having a new issue; being that the return value is now info when the method is expecting type A
